# Restriction of invariant measure with support in some compact set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading a paper, and have the following question:

Suppose we have the discrete-time dynamical system: $$x^+ = T(x)$$

1. The mapping $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a multivariate polynomial.
2. $\mu$, which is any nonnegative Borel measure, is an invariant measure: $$\mu(T^{-1}(A)) = \mu(A) \ \ \ \cdots (1)$$ for all Borel measurable $A\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Next, the paper `restricts attention to invariant measures with support included in some compact set` $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. With this, $(1)$ reduces to

$$\int_Xf\circ Td\mu = \int_Xfd\mu  \ \ \ \cdots (2)$$   for all $f\in C(X)$, where $C(X)$ is the space of continuous function  on $X$.

My question is why $(1)$ reduces to $(2)$? Can anyone please provide me with a detailed explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) is a special case of (2) when $f$ is the indicator of a Borel set $A \subset X$, i.e. $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in A \\ 0 & x \notin A\end{cases}$. Indeed for this $f$ we have $\int_X f \, d\mu = \mu(A)$ and $\int_X f \circ T \, d\mu = \mu\{x : T(x) \in A\} = \mu(T^{-1}(A))$.

In the other direction, (2) can be obtained from (1) by writing $f$ as a limit of simple functions. Specifically, if (1) holds, then you know (2) holds for $f$ being indicator functions of Borel sets. Thus, (2) also holds for [simple functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function) which are sums of indicator functions. As noted in the Wikipedia article, you can approximate any nonnegative function $f$ by such simple functions, so one can show (2) holds for such $f$ as well.

Comment: Could you please detail the answer a bit? I am still confused like 1. $X$ is union of $A$?  2. You mean write $f$ as $1$ when $x\in A$ and $0$ otherwise then LHS of (2) becomes LHS of (1)?  Thanks so much